# Give an example of a function $f$ holomorphic and not zero in $D(0;1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

> Give an example of a function $f$ which is holomorphic and not identically zero in $D(0;1)$ and such that the set of limit points of $Z(f)$ (the zeros of $f$) is $\{\pm 1 , \pm i\}$.

This is a starting problem in a chapter covering the Identity Theorem, and I'm stuck with it. So far, I've been only able to prove things such that "if $f(z)=g(z)$ on a set $S$, then $f=g$ in $G$".

I thought that maybe looking at the zeros of a trigonometric function or $f(z)=z^4-1$ might help, but I can't go further.

I'm not interested that much in a precise answer, but rather in how should I seek for such a function in case I stumble on a similar question later.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look up something called a Blaschke product.

Comment: what is $Z(f)$ ${}{}{}$

Comment: @T.Bongers Thanks! But a little too advanced I'm afraid...

Comment: @user1952009 $Z(f)$ stands for the zeros of $f$. I'll edit the question to make that clearer.

Comment: then what is the problem with $z^4-1$

Comment: and there is also $h(z) = \sin(\frac{1}{z-1})$ having a zero at each $\frac{1}{z-1} = \pi n$ i.e. $z = \frac{1}{\pi n}+1, n \in \mathbb{Z}^*$, so that $f(z) = h(z) h(-z) h(iz) h(-iz)$ has $\pm 1, \pm i$ in its limit points

Comment: @user1952009 It's just that the zeros of $z^4-1$ are $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$, but a finite set has no limit points, so I dismissed it.

Comment: @user1952009 Nice then! I should review those definitions in more detail. And how did you come up with that combination of $h(z)$ and conjugates?

Comment: @user1952009 The definition of a limit point usually excludes constant sequences. As such, $z^4 - 1$ does *not* satisfy the condition.

Comment: @T.Bongers yes I got it thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f(z) = \sin(1/(1-z^2)) \cdot \sin(1/(1+z^2)).$

Comment: you could propose $\sin(\frac{1}{z^4-1})$ it is more general

Comment: I just went with the first thing that came to mind. The problem on (−1,1) is a simple calculus problem, I rotated that, and then multiplied. I hadn't seen your comment when I posted btw.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [Blaschke products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product) as T. Bongers mentioned. This allows you to choose any sequence of zeros $(a_n)$ in the disk such that $\sum_n 1-|a_n|<\infty$, so here you could interweave $4$ sequences converging rapidly to $\pm1, \pm i$, e.g. $a_n=i^n(1-2^{-n})$.  The resulting function also maps into the disk.

With this method you can get any closed subset of the circle as the set of limit points of the set of zeros, whereas the approach using $\sin$ will handle any finite set.